# How to ensure html consistency in html emails?

Tags: phpmailer

I've seen that html in emails can be a bit problematic because because the suport is not great, if I need to send emails for account confirmations, password changes etc, I need to be sure that the recipient sees the email correctly, are there any tags that are supported by the most email providers ?

Can I reliably use anchor tags, and style them inline, should I just send users emails with the confirmation link and tell them to copy paste it?

Answer (score 0):

you can check it by copy-paste your web view in to different email service provider. Steps:

1. Open your email HTML in any browser.
2. press 'CTRL+A' and 'CTRL+C' or right click and copy option
3. Go to any Email service provider then got to **COMPOSE**
4. Paste your code.

It will give you view how it will see in email service provider. Do it with every email service provider.

Hope this will help :)